# urlFetch , Servlet and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, urlfetch

I'm developing a webapp in Appengine-Java. I'm a newbie in this field and i'm having a hard time.

I'm currently using a loop. Each loop accesses a certain isbn from a list then gets the details of the books through urlFetch. My problem is I want to improve its performance by using a thread instead of a loop however java supports one superclass only and i can't extend thread. Any ideas?

Comment: Additional : I'm planning to use thread so that those threads will look for the details of the book simultaneously. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the network bandwidth won't increase if you use more threads.

Answer (score 0):

App engine has restrictions about threads. Make sure to read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox.

Regarding your inheritance problem, extending Thread can't be done in app engine, and is bad practice anyway. You should implement Runnable, and follow the documentation I linked to to execute it in app engine.